# How to search by other thing that not is Id in Spring Boot with MongoDB Repository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm making a application in which I want to search a city by its name.The database from where I extract the information is a MongoDB database with the attributes of id, city, location, population and state. I have the following Entity:

```
 public class Cities {
        @Id
        private String _id;
        private String city;
        private String[] loc;
        private String pop;
        private String state;

        public String get_id() {
            return _id;
        }

        public void set_id(String _id) {
            this._id = _id;
        }

        String getLocation() {
            return loc[0] + " " + loc[1];
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String[] getLoc() {
            return loc;
        }

        public void setLoc(String[] loc) {
            this.loc = loc;
        }

        public String getPop() {
            return pop;
        }

        public void setPop(String pop) {
            this.pop = pop;
        }

        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cities{" +
                    "_id='" + _id + '\'' +
                    ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                    ", loc=" + Arrays.toString(loc) +
                    ", pop='" + pop + '\'' +
                    ", state='" + state + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
import com.sbmongo.starbucks.Constant.ViewConstant;
import com.sbmongo.starbucks.Entity.Cities;
import com.sbmongo.starbucks.Repository.CitiesRepository;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/starbucks")
public class CitiesController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("citiesRepository")
    private CitiesRepository citiesRepository;

    @GetMapping("/cities")
    public ModelAndView listCities(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ViewConstant.CITIES);
        mav.addObject("cities", citiesRepository.findAll());
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchCity")
    public ModelAndView searchCity(@RequestParam(name = "city", required = false)String city){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ViewConstant.CITIES);
        mav.addObject("cities", citiesRepository.findByCity(city));
        return mav;
    }
}
```

My Repository:

```
import java.util.List;

@Repository("citiesRepository")
public interface CitiesRepository extends MongoRepository<Cities, String> {
    public Cities findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
    public Cities findByCity(String city);
}
```

And the HTML in which I'm using Thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Starbucks</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Population</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="city : ${cities}">
                    <td th:text="${city._id}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${city.city}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${#strings.arrayJoin(city.loc, ' ')}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${city.pop}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${city.state}"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to search a city by his name, I send the name of the city from the View and recive it in the Controller, but looks like my findByCity() method in the Repository doesn't work. 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findByCity() should return a list
try:

```
 public List<Cities> findByCity(String city);
```